# How are primary reserves activated for frequency control?

Tags: power, frequency, generator, power-grid

How are primary reserves activated for primary frequency control? In particular I have the following doubts:

1. Is there a frequency threshold where each of them are automatically activated or they are activated manually by someone?
2. Are each of them always entirely released when activated or can be activated partially?
3. Are primary reserves currently provided by renewables in Europe?

Comment: https://mdpi-res.com/d_attachment/energies/energies-14-01456/article_deploy/energies-14-01456-v2.pdf the contribution factors are determined as the
sum of the electricity generation and consumption in the control area i divided by the
sum of the total electricity generation and consumption in the whole CE synchronous area.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thank you! Reading the document you attached there is the power frequency characterisric of the CE system equal to 27000-30000 MW/Hz. Is this power frequency characterisric true only up to 200 mHz of deviation (end of primary control) right?

Comment: It is controlled by GW/Hz and Hz deviation of grid capacity with the group Power authority. for example Ukraine did a years worth of work in 2 weeks and converted grid from RU to EU as RU blasted connections.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is there a frequency threshold where each of them are automatically activated or they are activated manually by someone?

Reserves will be activated by consumer power / energy demand.

> 2. Are each of them always entirely released when activated or can be activated partially?

Why would they be? It's not like a solid-rocket booster that can't be switched off. Consider a hydro pumped-storage system. That can be stopped or reversed at any stage of its pumping or generating cycle.

> 3. Are primary reserves currently provided by renewables in Europe?

No. The big, largely unsolved problem with renewables is the lack of storage. The main idea with renewables is to use them as the primary source when available (sunshine / wind / tide) and only use the thermal plants as required.

Comment: thank you! Just one question. Consider this example: a reserve is activated. After the activation of the reserve frequency continues to change, is the reserve still constant or it increases/decreases according to the additional frequency variation?

Comment: In general the output can be increased or decreased by controlling the amount of fuel fed into the generator.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a frequency threshold where each of them are automatically activated or they are activated manually by someone?

That depends on the design of the network. Usually there's a mix of the two.

> Are each of them always entirely released when activated or can be activated partially?

Again, depends on the design of the network. Sometimes partial activation is a matter of necessity. E.g. if out of 5 equivalent peaker plants available, two are down: you can only activate 60% of the peaker capacity for frequency control.

But that's when you *need* to activate all 5 peakers. If you only need one per current demand for frequency control, then partial activation is the desirable and only reasonable option.

Comment: thank you! Just one question? Consider this example: a partial reserve is activated (non because of fault or maintenance on the other part of the reserve). Can this be done? And another thing: if after the activation of the partial reserve frequency continues to change, is the partial reserve still constant or it increases/decreases according to the additional frequency variation?